# Как задать имя и расширение файла?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Никак не получается сделать загрузку изображений с адекватным расширением и именем файла.

На сервер отправляется параметр `images_attributes` - массив картинок в `base64`. Затем в *Paperclip* обрабатываются файлы и сохраняются. Проблема в том, что библиотека *Paperclip* сохраняет имя файла как "data" без расширения и имя не меняется.

Какими методами можно манипулировать расширением и именем файла до сохранения?

Comment: Вопрос решился, только теперь сохраняется файл с двумя расширениями, к примеру: .jpg.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос был решен следующим образом:

before_create :randomize_file_name

```
def randomize_file_name
    ext = Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert[image_content_type]
    self.image.instance_write(:file_name, "#{SecureRandom.uuid}#{ext}")
  end
```